# C#: Looping through member objects of nested structs

Tags: c#, struct, reflection, iteration, packed

Hi all you c# wizards!

**I need to store all the memory offset values of (packed) nested structs within these respective structs.**
Recusively looping through all the members works fine so far. Also, i get the appropriate memory offset values.
This struct contraption might contain several dozends of structs, and several hundreds of other members in the end.
But i do this whole thing at initialization time, so CPU performance won't be an issue here.

---

### But:

**In this iteration process, it seems i have trouble accessing the actual *instances* of those structs. As it turns out, when i try to store these offset values, they don't end up where i need them** (of course, i need them in the instance "SomeStruct1" and its containing other struct instances, but the debugger clearly shows me the init values (-1)).

I suspect "field_info.GetValue" or "obj_type.InvokeMember" is not the proper thing to get the object reference? Is there any other way to loop through nested struct *instances*?

**Please help!** I've desperately debugged and googled for three days, but i'm so out of ideas now...

Thanks for your efforts!

-Albert

---

PS - the reason i do this unusual stuff:
I communicate between two embedded CPU cores via the mentioned nested struct (both are mixed c/c++ projects). This works like a charm, as both cores share the same memory, where the struct resides.

Additionally, i have to communicate between a c# host application and theses embedded cores, so i thought it could be a neat thing, if i implement a third instance of this struct. Only this time, i oviously can't use shared RAM. Instead, i implement value setters and getters for the data-holding members, find out the memory offset as well as the lenght of the data-holding members, and feed this information (along with the value itself) via USB or Ethernet down to the embedded system - so the "API" to my embedded system will simply be a struct. The only maintenance i have to do every thime i change the struct: i have to copy the holding .h file (of the embedded project) to a .cs file (host project).
I know it's crazy - but it works now.

Thanks for your interest. -Albert

---

This is a simplified (buggy, see below) example that should compile and execute (WinForms, c#7.3):

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CodingExample
{
    public interface Interf
    {
        Int32   Offset  {get; set; }
    }

    [StructLayout (LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct sSomeStruct2 : Interf
    {
        public sSomeStruct2 (bool dummy)
        {
            Offset      = -1;
            SomeMember3 = 0;
        }
        public Int32    Offset  {get; set; }
    
        public Int32    SomeMember3;
        // much more various-typed members (e. g. nested structs)...
    }

    [StructLayout (LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct sSomeStruct1 : Interf
    { 
        public sSomeStruct1 (bool dummy)
        {
            Offset      = -1;
            SomeMember1 = 0;
            SomeStruct2 = new sSomeStruct2 (true);
            SomeMember2 = 0;
        }
        public Int32        Offset  {get; set; }

        public Int32        SomeMember1;
        public sSomeStruct2 SomeStruct2;
        public Int16        SomeMember2;
        // much more various-typed members...
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        void InitializeOffsets (object obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("obj: {0}", obj);

            Type obj_type   = obj.GetType ();

            foreach (FieldInfo field_info in obj_type.GetFields ())
            { 
                string field_name   = field_info.Name;
                Int32 offset        = (Int32) Marshal.OffsetOf (obj_type, field_name);
                Type field_type     = field_info.FieldType;
                bool is_leafe       = field_type.IsPrimitive;

// none of theses three options seem to give me the right reference:
//                object node_obj     = field_info.GetValue (obj);
//                object node_obj     = field_info.GetValue (null);
                object node_obj     = obj_type.InvokeMember (field_name, BindingFlags.GetField, null, obj, null);

                Console.WriteLine ("field: {0}; field_type: {1}; is_leafe: {2}; offset: {3}", field_name, field_type, is_leafe, offset); 

                if (! is_leafe)
                {
// this writes not as expected:                    
                    (node_obj as Interf).Offset = offset;
    
                    InitializeOffsets (node_obj);
                }
            }
        }

        sSomeStruct1 SomeStruct1; 

        public Form1 ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            SomeStruct1 = new sSomeStruct1 (true);

            InitializeOffsets (SomeStruct1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should describe what you want to do. What you do this all for. There must be a better solution, C# has never been about byte pushing and offset counting in memory structures.

Comment: What do you mean by *"the right reference"*? You have structs. They're getting boxed. Passing as `object`, casting to `Interf`... new references are being created and discarded all over the place. The original `SomeStruct1` that you pass to `InitializeOffsets` is getting copied; the original is unaffected by all this. Use classes instead.

Comment: @nvoigt: I agree, there must be a better solution. Okay, i'll add a description why i do this thing.

Comment: @madreflection: you are right. I have trouble avoiding copies. Unfortunately, i need structs.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile i found out, what i did wrong:

1. i have to do boxing, so i can use "ref" when i call my initialize function:

```
// instead of this:
SomeStruct1 = new sSomeStruct1 (true);

// i have to do it this way:
object boxed_SomeStruct1 = new sSomeStruct1 (true);
InitializeOffsets (ref boxed_SomeStruct1);
SomeStruct1 = (sSomeStruct1) boxed_SomeStruct1;
```

2. Within the "InitializeOffsets" function, "field_info.GetValue (obj)" delivers a *copy* of my member object. That's why i have to copy the modified copy back at the very end of the foreach loop:

```
field_info.SetValue (obj, node_obj);
```

After these changes, the code works as intended.
Thanks for your interest. -Albert